# compare two files and update the differences to 2nd file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use PowerShell using `Get-Content` to read 2 files and update the changes in file 1 to file 2, here is my code:

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content c:\file1) (Get-Content c:file2) | diff > (Get-Content c:file2)
```

and its not working, I need to append the file so it appends any changes to the 2nd file.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues here

1. You are calling `diff` but in PowerShell that is an alias for `Compare-Object` which you see from `get-alias diff`. I am guessing that was not expected.
2. If you want to append the differences that occur in the first file you need to filter the output from `compare-object` accordingly.

So with that in mind I present...

```
$file1 = "c:\file1"
$file2 = "c:\file2"
Compare-Object (Get-Content $file1) (Get-Content $file2) | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Add-Content $file2
```

`$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="` Will only allow the entries that are unique to `$file1` to continue thru the pipe to `Add-Content`. If you just look at the output of `compare-object` before the `Where-Object` you can get a good idea of whats going on.