# Compare two Files and list only the differences of 2nd File using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get the current list of azure vms on first run of script -> Stores to Storage Account in CSV File
O the 2nd run - Current List should be compared with existing csv file in Storage Account incase of any vms decommisioned that should be recorded and stored in 2nd File in Storage Account

This works fine for me but the issue is when we create a new azure vm which was also gets added to decommission csv list

**$Difference = Compare-Object $existingVmCsv $vmrecordFile -Property VmName -PassThru | Select-Object VmName,ResourceGroupName,SubscriptionName**

I tried couple of side indicators but dint work

1. $Difference = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($vmrecordFile | Select-Object) -DifferenceObject @($existingVmCsv | Select-Object) -PassThru -Property VmName,ResourceGroupName,SubscriptionName | Where-Object {$_sideIndicator -eq "<="}
2. $Difference = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $vmrecordFile -DifferenceObject $existingVmCsv -PassThru -Property VmName,ResourceGroupName,SubscriptionName | Where-Object {$_sideIndicator -eq "<="}

Comment: Looks like you have a typo? Object property references should use a `.`, like `Where-Object { $_.sideIndicator -eq '<=' }`

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [User Cpt.Whale - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7411885/cpt-whale) . Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

> It seems, you have a typo in a syntax. Object property references should use a `"."` , like `Where-Object { $_.sideIndicator -eq '<=' }`

`'<='`  This indicates that property value appears only in the `-ReferenceObject` set`References:` [powershell - compare two files and update the differences to 2nd file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107605/compare-two-files-and-update-the-differences-to-2nd-file) , [Powershell : How to Compare Two Files, and List Differences | | Dotnet Helpers (dotnet-helpers.com)](https://dotnet-helpers.com/powershell/compare-two-files-list-differences/) and [compare-object not working : PowerShell (reddit.com)](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/6295hs/compareobject_not_working/)